# Prevent Contact Form 7 Refresh of form fields

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have an issue with CF7 where upon submission and before my redirect occurs, my form refreshes...
This creates the sense to the user that nothing has happened and may cause users to bounce. The redirect does work, and takes about 3-4 seconds which is fine, but the instant refresh of the form could confuse the user. Is there a way to prevent the form from refreshing?

Here is our page with the CF7 form on top for reference:
https://coversearch.co.za/test-car-insurance-homepage/

Answer (score 2):

no, it's not possible, CF7 js scripts uses the JavaScript [HTMLFormElement `reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method to clear the fields once the form submission success event is fired.

However, there is a way to re-populate the values of the fields after they have been reset using the [defaultValue property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) of an input field.  This is a hack I use on one of my plugins to enable a 'save draft' button on a cf7 form (allowing users to submit and save partially submitted forms) and therefore shows values of fields filled in after submission.  You will need to enqueue this script on the page on which your form is being displayed,

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $('form.wpcf7-form input[type=submit].wpcf7-submit').on('click', function(event){
        let $form = $(this).closest('form.wpcf7-form');
        
        
        $(':input',$form).each(function(){
            let $this = $(this);
            switch(true){
              case $this.is(':checked'):
                $this.prop("defaultChecked", true);
                break;
              case $this.is('select'):
                let values = $this.val();
                if(!$.isArray(values)) values = [values];
                $('option', $this).each(function(){
                  let $option = $(this);
                  $option[0].defaultSelected= false;
                  if(values.indexOf($option.val()) >= 0){
                    $option[0].defaultSelected=true;
                  }
                });
                break;
              default:
                $this.prop("defaultValue", $this.val());
                break;
            }
        }); //input each

      }); //submit click
      
    });//document ready

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks Aurovrata, appreciate the feedback and providing an option to try atleast